# How do I get the password from the su command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, suse

I am copying files from a remote server to my local server. Here is the code that does this:

```
ssh -q username@$192.168.162.156 "su -lc 'cp /copy/from /copy/it/here'"
```

I am using this code segment in a for loop so it will prompt for a password for every iteration. How do I get the password from the `su` command? (without using rsync or sudo). I also don't want any alternatives even if they are better.

Comment: Do you really need the `su` command? Can't you just copy the files like: `ssh <user>@<host> cat /<path_to_file>/<filename> > <local_filename>`

Comment: I'd expect `expect` to solve this. So many threads already about this. Try to search for `ssh expect`.

Answer (score 2):

Execute in local server:

`scp remote_user@remote_server:/path/to/files /dir/to/copy`

When executed in local machine, this logon to *remote_server* as user *remote_user* and copy the files in */path/to/files/* in remote server to */dir/to/copy/* in local server.

You might want to setup a [passwordless ssh](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~bigler/code/sshkeys.html) connection to run it in a script which requires no passwords.

Read [`man scp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the password via stdin:

```
echo 'password' | su -c [...]
```

Comment: This will fortunately not work, because it is insecure.

Comment: Obtaining the password from `su` would be insecure too (but fortunately cannot be done).

Answer (score 0):

If repetitive promt for password is your problem, you may try

1. Create passwordless ssh setup between host
2. Use `new ssh module` of perl
3. Tar all you files and then send it over network. This way only one tar file is send and password prompt will only be for once.